# yii2 blank page issue in all crud create and update actions

Tags: yii2-basic-app

Please help me.
I have problem as follow:
At the localhost everything ok.
But, at hosting after model save method, controller redirect method return blank page without any error.

my code here:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
$model = new Project();

$file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
if($file) {
$path = 'uploads/projects/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
$file->saveAs($path);
$model->image = $path;
$model->save(false);
}
return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
} else {
return $this->render('create', [
'model' => $model,
]);
}
}
```

But redirect method works normally outside model save() method.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

**Edited:**

```
   public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Project();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

            if($file) {
               $path = 'uploads/projects/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
               $file->saveAs($path);
               $model->image = $path;
               $model->save(false);
           }
           return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
           return $this->render('create', [
               'model' => $model,
           ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `UploadedFile` after `$model` data posted.

Comment: problem occurred all my created and updated actions, everything going well, but redirect, goHome() etc, cannot work normally, it returns empty page. But without any form redirect method working normally.

Comment: replace `$file` with `$model->file`

Comment: No thank, i thing problem depends on hosting, but i cannot solve it